# How to make a superclass that encapsulates a thread with RAII

Tags: c++, c++17

I've just started learning C++ and I'm writing an n-body gravity simulator as a learning exercise. To learn about threading I decided to split the work between a render thread (display state on screen) and a simulate thread (advance the simulation).

RAII seems important so the render thread is using it to turn the console's cursor visible and invisible while it's alive based on an InvisibleCursor object who manages that state in its constructor & destructor. That works and is not pictured. The problem was that I had been shutting down the threads by just letting a Ctrl-C bubble up, which calls terminate() on the threads, which does not call local destructors, apparently.

So the threads should exit themselves, fine. I decided to try to use RAII for them too, resulting in an object which had a thread and a method and a stop flag member variable. On construction, the object initialized its thread to run its method, and the method checked the member stop flag every so often and stopped when it was true. This works and is not pictured. The problem is when I tried to pull out that logic (since I have 2 of these threads) into a superclass and have each thread type subclass them. This only sort of works and is pictured.

The issue I believe is that I'm calling the now-virtual action method in my base constructor, which according to the internet is a big no-no, and which I've observed makes whether it works or not a race condition.

In terms of other approaches, I also tried having Threader take the action as a lambda instead of subclassing it, and it worked but it became very unpleasant to work with due to the types involved.

My questions include: How can I do this? Is there something obvious I've missed? Does a thing like this already exist and I should just use that? Is this just a totally flawed approach?

I would also greatly appreciate general advice and/or links to resources. If it wasn't obvious I am very much still learning C++.

I am using clang++ v6.0 with -lpthread and --std=c++17 on Ubuntu 18.04

Minimal-ish reproducing example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class Thing {
public:
  void tick() { std::cout << "tick" << std::endl; };
};

class Threader {
protected:
  bool stop;

public:
  std::thread th;

  virtual void action() = 0;

  void run() {
    std::cout << "th run" << std::endl;
    action();
  };

  Threader() : stop(false), th(std::thread(&Threader::run, this)){};

  ~Threader() {
    std::cout << "destructed" << std::endl;
    stop = true;
    if (th.joinable()) {
      th.join();
    }
  }
};

class SimulateThread : Threader {
  std::mutex &mx;
  std::shared_ptr<Thing> thing_p;
  int sleep_millis;

public:
  SimulateThread(std::mutex &mx, std::shared_ptr<Thing> thing_p,
                 int sleep_millis)
      : mx(mx), thing_p(thing_p), sleep_millis(sleep_millis){};

  void action() {
    for (;;) {
      if (stop) {
        std::cout << "stopping" << std::endl;
        return;
      }
      {
        auto lock = std::scoped_lock(mx);
        thing_p.get()->tick();
      }
      if (sleep_millis > 0)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_millis));
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  auto thing = Thing{};
  auto thing_p = std::make_shared<Thing>(thing);
  auto mx = std::mutex{};
  {
    auto st = SimulateThread{mx, thing_p, 100};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }

  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ make && ./threadthing
clang++ --std=c++17 -lpthread threadthing.cpp -o threadthing
th run
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
destructed
stopping
done
```

So it is working. But when I change the main call to this:

```
int main() {
  auto thing = Thing{};
  auto thing_p = std::make_shared<Thing>(thing);
  auto mx = std::mutex{};
  {
    auto st = SimulateThread{mx, thing_p, 100};
  }
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is this:

```
$ make && ./threadthing
clang++ --std=c++17 -lpthread threadthing.cpp -o threadthing
destructed
th run
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

(exited with code 134)

As far as I understand it, this should behave the same way, except never printing "tick" or maybe only once. The fact that it doesn't tells me there's a race condition between the std::thread actually starting after it's initialized and the SimulateThread instance being fully initialized.

Notes about the example:

- In the full program main waits forever, catches a Ctrl-C, and exits the block with my thread objects in them. This example just waits and exits but that should work the same w.r.t. this issue.
- I think the stop flag should be wrapped in a std::atomic. Y/n?
- It gets a shared_ptr (by value) to the shared state it is using, and uses a scoped_lock on a mutex shared between the threads (by reference) so each can access it without races. Is that right?

Version using lambdas, for posterity:

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
template <typename F> class Threader {
  volatile bool stop;
  F action;

public:
  void run() {
    std::cout << "th run" << std::endl;
    action(stop);
  };

  std::thread th;

  Threader(F action)
      : stop(false), action(action), th(std::thread(&Threader::run, this)){};

  ~Threader() {
    stop = true;
    if (th.joinable()) {
      th.join();
    }
  }
};

int main() {

  auto thing_p = std::make_shared<Thing>(thing);
  auto mx = std::mutex{};

  auto simulator = Threader{[&mx, thing_p](volatile bool &stop) {
    for (;;) {
      if (stop) {
        return;
      }
      {
        auto lock = std::scoped_lock(mx);
        thing_p.get()->tick();
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
    }
  }};

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

The thing I like least about the approach with lambdas is having the implementation of the lambda be in the calling method. But when I tried to pull it out into a function returning the Threader instance I got stuck in the types.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

The reason you're getting this message is because you have a very subtle race condition on your object's vptr.  Since `virtual` calls don't work in constructors or destructors (sub-objects haven't been constructed yet), many implementations update the vptr as constructors/destructors are entered.  In your case, the thread is trying to start before the object is fully constructed.  You also have the same problem in your destructor, since by the time you try to `join`, the child object has already been destroyed.

The solution is that you need to start and join your thread on fully constructed objects (e.g., outside of your `class` hierarchy); your lambda version does this.

Comment: There's an example of this problem being detected by clang from Going Native 2013: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/The-Care-and-Feeding-of-C-s-Dragons (skip to 1:13:00 if you don't want to watch the whole talk).

Comment: Sorry, tsan in general starts at 1:13:00, but the vptr race starts a bit before 1:19:00.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that video out later. Yeah I figured that was the issue. Can you elaborate on the race in the destructor? Since there are no virtual calls in there it should be safe no? Also, a broader question -- what's the best approach to make something that behaves this way? The lambda implementation? I really struggled with the types when trying to make a function that returns an instance of Threader with the lambda filled in -- trying to pull the actual logic out of main(). Would you mind giving an example of that?

Comment: Could I maybe do something like move the thread initialization into the subclass's constructor? Have the base provide like an init() method for it to call with a reference to the subclass's implementation of the virtual function? I suppose I'm looking for a way forward more than an explanation here.

Comment: When your base `class`'s destructor is entered, any child `class`es have already had their destructors run.  This means that if the work function hasn't already stopped, any member variables child `class`es declare have been destructed.  Depending on what types those variables are, you could hit any number of memory issues.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. That is a very subtle bug